# Does the App Store allow web apps to be "wrapped" in a native container?

Tags: iphone, ios4

If I do ***just*** this in my iPhone app:

```
     NSString *urlAddress = @"http:www.mobilewebapp.com";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webV loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Will Apple allow me to publish this app on the App Store, just adding web location to my web view in native app?

Answer (score 4):

No, Apple will likely not allow this to get through the approval process. As far as functionality goes, this app does very little. All it does is load a webpage. According to the App Review guidelines you're likely not going to get very far.

(I'm guessing that you saw [this article on slashdot](http://apple.slashdot.org/story/11/03/15/1642213/Apple-Handcuffs-Web-Apps-On-iPhone-Home-Screen) and are wondering how to protect your web app.)

Comment: If there is no added functionality in the native app that does not exist in the web app, I can confirm that you will get rejected.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the App Store allow web apps to be “wrapped” in a native
>   container?

No. Apple expressly rejects web apps, see their review guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). At the time of writing this late answer, the key section reads:

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, **are simply web sites bundled as Apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
>   be rejected

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine to use, assuming your application performs other operations as well. However if this is all it does, Apple is likely to reject it since it duplicates the functionality of Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that they will reject such an app for doing nothing that a built-in program (Safari) doesn't do.